# Get Google sheet last modification date in C#.NET with Google Sheets API v4

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

(I'm asking this question because I already searched in all the documentation and there is nothing about) here is my code:

```
        string credencialesJson = "path/to/my/json/credentials/file";
        string spreadsheetId = "aSheetId";

        GoogleCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(credencialesJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                .CreateScoped(new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets });
        }

        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "MySHeet"
        });
```

I just want to know how to get the date the sheet or an specific row or column were modified

I'm using the Google Sheet API v4

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
```